# Linear Mixed-Effects Models (lmer function in R) - Statistical significance?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, model-selection

I have the following mixed models:

```
modeloIa<-lmer(log(FstPSAmm2+1)~AntherAreamm2+(1|plant), REML = F)

modeloIIa<-lmer(log(FstPSAmm2+1)~AntherAreamm2*color+(1|plant), REML = F)

modeloIIIa<-lmer(log(FstPSAmm2+1)~AntherAreamm2*color*FlPerBranch+(1|plant), REML = F)

modeloIVa<-lmer(log(FstPSAmm2+1)~color*AntherAreamm2*PlVoldm3+(1|plant), REML = F)
```

The first one is the null modell. The variable **color** is the fixed effect I want to test. **FlPerBranch** and **PlVoldm3** are covariables.

How do I select the best model? How do I know if the variables are significant?
These two questions are for me a dilemma.

If I use the AIC criterion I should select one model, but if I use the likelihood ratio test, starting from my null modell, I should select another. Any advice will help me a lot, thanks.

Comment: Looking through [our previous questions tagged both "mixed-model" and "model-selection"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-model%2bmodel-selection) gives a number of hits. Does anything there help you?

Comment: See the help file `?lmer` for examples of performing tests with mixed effects models.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at mixed effect model selection in Zuur et al. (2009) (? maybe 2007)
You could use AICc to aid in model selection for sure but I know he goes into it a lot more in his book. 
As for the p-values there are two ways I know of. One way would be to install the package `lmerTest` it gives you pvalues for you model outputs. The other way that I know more about is to use anova (with a chi-square distrib.) in order to get some sort of p-values.

For example if you do an AICc on two models
model1 is Y ~ x+(1|y)
model2 is Y ~x + z +(1|y)  and the aic difference is extremely close you can run an anova on both:

```
aov(model1,model2, type = "chisq")
```

and get a p -value telling you the significance of that extra parameter (z)

Comment: Can you give a little more information, maybe a link, to the paper/book you are citing?

Comment: http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387874579